# How to add Stroke in UILabel Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

> While add Stroke to UILabel App Crashes

---

It Crash due to found nil

```
let strokeTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor : UIColor.green,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightGray,
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth : -4.0,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 52)
    ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

hello_cell_lb.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "\(hello_array[indexPath.row])", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
```

Comment: Worked for me. You might have a `nil` `hello_cell_lb`. Where are you adding this code? Please do it in a place where `hello_cell_lb` is initialised.

Comment: What is the `nil` in your code? I would assume that `strokeTextAttributes` should work fine.

Comment: worked for me too. make sure your `UILabel` is not nil.

Comment: Can you paste log message here?

Comment: where do you execute this code in cellForRow ????

Comment: Removed Cocoa Tag

Comment: "App Crashes" It crashes? What's the error message? Because clearly that could be helpful. Which line exactly causes the crash? Did you try to separate line by line?

Comment: Not in a cell row. its in view did load

Comment: 'Nil Attribute found' Error message

Answer (score 0):

You seem to add stroke to a nil label in cell but it works here

[image]

Comment: Label is not nil. i try this code in another view, result is same crash.Before execute the code label assign it crashed, Is your swift 3?

Comment: what is crash says comment the log in console here

Comment: Crashed while executing Stroke text Attribute, It says that NSAttributedStringKey found nil